# Margin в процентах и flex

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox, margin

Если задать margin-left у `li` в `px`, то верстка не сломается и родительский элемент расширится, но если указать в `%`, то верстка сломается и ширина родительского элемента не увеличится.

```css
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body{
 padding: 15px;
 width: 200%;
}
div{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
li{
 list-style: none;
}

a{
 text-decoration: none;
}

header{
 background: #f6f6f6;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-pack: justify;
     -ms-flex-pack: justify;
         justify-content: space-between;
 -webkit-box-align: center;
     -ms-flex-align: center;
         align-items: center;
 padding: 20px 7%;
}

a{
 color: #292929;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 25px 10px;
}

a:hover{
 background: #ffea00;
}

li{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 4%;
}

#menu-checkbox{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-LwKGZ5rLuwk/W36DnkeoqtI/AAAAAAAAAKs/M-d_UhhrosQHtigp6pqn7t_lozY6HRtNgCJoC/w530-h530-n-rw/LOGO.png" height="116px">
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-checkbox">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <label for="menu-checkbox" class="toggle-button" data-open="Menu" data-close="Close" onclick></label>
      <ul class="main-menu">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: А `body{width:200%}` это зачем?

Comment: так-как в этом мини-окне не будет видно сломанного меню

Comment: Свойство margin-left может быть выражено как ключевое слово auto, или как <число>, или как <процент>. Значение может быть положительным, нулевым или отрицательным. <число> - Размер отступа - фиксированная величина.
<процент> -  Размер отступа в процентах - размер относительно длины родительского блока.